# MacBook Pro password contains #\~- symbols how do i get this correct

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings, internationalization

I have just purchased a new MacBook Pro and having a lot of difficulty trying to log in, the keyboard has been set to British and my password contains the following characters

- `#` I press the following keys to get this: <kbd>Opt</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> or do I need to press these together or keep the <kbd>Opt</kbd> and then <kbd>3</kbd>
- `\` is by itself
- `~` I do <kbd>Shift</kbd> beside the <kbd>Z</kbd> which has a <kbd>~</kbd> on it
- `=` by itself <kbd>=</kbd>
- `+` is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>
- `-` is <kbd>-</kbd>

I've tried a few variations of the above but am still unable to log into my user account.

The password field does not show what I've entered, can this be enabled to help me?

[image: Photo of a MacBook Pro keyboard with British keyboard layout]

Comment: I made some grammatical and formatting changes that I hope will be what you mean. Please review them to see if they are correct. If not, you can click the [edit] under your post to make any necessary changes/additions.

Comment: Are you totally sure your keyboard was set to British and not British PC, which is different for #, which moves to the last key in the asdf row, and tilde and backslash also move, tilde to shift # and backslash to the key to the left of z.

Comment: Based on [How to identify your Apple keyboard layout by country or region](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794), the keyboard in the photo would be an ISO keyboard with a British/Irish layout.

Comment: Hi Agarza, thanks for correcting my grammer, thanks

Comment: Hi Tom, yes definately British - A British